# Ubuntu 14.04 looks too slow

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on my PC.

- E5500 Dual core 2.8Ghz Processor,
- 4GB RAM,
- GT610 1GB Graphic card,
- 80 GB Hard Disk (for Ubuntu), 500GB Hard disk (Windows 8)

Everything is slow. I mean when am moving a window it is moving slow,when minimizing, restoring, the item bar,everything is slow. Why is that? please someone help me to fix this.

Comment: Try installing Nvidia driver from Additional Drivers.

Comment: @fleamour .. Thanks buddy.... problem solved.... thanks a lot.... :)

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem for me too: with my i7 workstation with nvdia graphics and my i3 laptop. Many people reported this and the admins closed the question calling the 'too broad.' I find that response condescending from the admins. Now I have been able to solve the issue on both my laptop and desktop. Here's how:

Install the unity tweak tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Once installed, open the tool and open *General* under the *Window Manager* section. The first parameter you see there is *zoom*. Switch the *Desktop Magnification* to *off*.

For me this has been causing all the problem. The computer was generally slow in spite of the system monitor not showing any considerable load. Now the issue is resolved for me and a couple of my friends too.